# Angular2 HTTP request not appending headers

Tags: angular, http

In my application, I am trying to send a quick test request to my API to test my authentication.  When a button is clicked, this function is called, which creates an Authorization header and makes an HTTP request:

```
  public test() {
    const headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token);
    this.http.get('http://localhost:62940/api/ping/secure', { headers: headers }).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

However, when I'm debugging (or analyzing traffic using Fiddler), `headers` has the header that I created, but nothing is being appended to the Http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`RequestOptions`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html) and append header to.

```
let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token);
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.get(URL, options).subscribe(x => {
     console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Can you show what is "Not work"? By provide error log, or when you call the service? Then replace `const` by `let`. You are create local variable, right?

Comment: Yep, no problem.  When I make the request, this is what my request headers look like:

OPTIONS http://localhost:62940/api/ping/secure HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:62940
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br

Comment: Make sure your server allow cross origin request (and allow `OPTIONS` request). Its easier to test that your HTTP request is correct or not by try to get local json file and see the response. Tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data-with-_http-get-_

Comment: Ah, perfect! It was always working, but apprently when the server throws an error (for an unrelated reason), chrome doesn't show the token

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

If you are making a CORS request, you need to add the "withCredentials: true" RequestOption with the HTTP request. Otherwise, authorization headers will not be added with the request.

```
public test() {
   const headers: Headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token);
   this.http.get('http://localhost:62940/api/ping/secure', {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: headers
   }).subscribe(x => {
       console.log(x);
   });
}
```

You also need to make sure that your server will accept the Authorization header by adding an "Acess-Control-Allow-Credentials = true" header to the pre-flight response, though this is different from server to server. Also, make sure CORS is enabled on the server as well.